# an example of a nested form in simple form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, simple-form

I am still struggling both writing the controller and the actual form to be able to nest one form in another with an optional model?

I have Message which has many contacts

When submitting a message, I want to add a contact optionally.

I have this as an example:

```
= simple_form_for Message.new, :remote => true do |f|
  #message_form
    = f.error_messages
    %p
      = f.input :account_name, :url => autocomplete_account_name_messages_path, :size => 40, :as => :autocomplete
    %p
      = f.input :topic, :required => true,
                :input_html => {:size => 30}

    #add_contact_btn
      = link_to "Add Contact"

      #contact_form
        = f.simple_fields_for :contactd do |fc|
        = fc.input :email
        = fc.input :first_name
        = fc.input :last_name

    = f.submit 'Give'
    = f.submit 'Request'
```

For Message.rb model, I have the following:

```
has_many :contacts
accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts, :reject_if =>:all_blank
```

Note:  When I used :contacts in the simple_fields_for it didn't work, so it is singular.  But the reverse for accepts_nested_attributess_for.

In my create controller for message, I included message.contacts.build

But right now I am still generating nil contacts.

Here is what I see passed as form data from google chrome:

```
message%5Baccount_name%5D:McKesson
message%5Btopic%5D:testing a contact
message%5Bbody%5D:testing this
sender_id:
receiver_id:23
message%5Bcontacts%5D%5Bemail%5D:888@gmail.com
message%5Bcontacts%5D%5Bfirst_name%5D:Ang
message%5Bcontacts%5D%5Blast_name%5D:Name
```

Comment: What happens when I pull it out from the partial is that there are no input fields in the fc contact form

Comment: Show the code for the partial, and the render-line.

Answer (score 8):

The correct method name is `simple_fields_for` (notice the plural)

Also, you need to keep the `f.` to call it on the simple_form object

Comment: Hmm...I get an error when I put the 'f.' -- but I put it in a partial, would that affect it?

Comment: also, do I need to do anything in the controller so that the contact is created?

Comment: Yes, if you put it inside a partial, you need to pass the local variable along, for example `render "fields", :f => f`. Since you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the model, it should work fine if you just call `@message.save` in the controller

Comment: ahhh.....thank you.  I am getting closer to making this work, I hope.  Let me give it a go and see....what types of associations will this work with?  will it workw tih both belongs_to contact and has_many :contacts?

Comment: do you have suggestions on how to debug this...I *still* am not creating contacts....must be something to do with the accepts_nested_attributes_for........

Answer (score 4):

I have a small project where I demonstrate how to use nested forms in simple-form, combined with cocoon (a gem I created to add/remove nested elements dynamically).

The project is on [github](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon_simple_form_demo).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks...I still don't get anything working -- no Contact is created :(

Answer (score 0):

> In my create controller for message, I included message.contacts.build
>
> But right now I am still generating nil contacts.

Make sure you put in your Message.rb model the ability for it to accept the attributes too.

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :contacts_attributes
    has_many :contacts
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts
```

I know it doesn't answer your question fully but it may have just been this. When it comes to my project, it would return nil if i didn't include the `:contacts_attributes`, in my case it deals with products. Hope this helps even if I'm not using simple form as of now!

Comment: okay, let me try that...it's the first time I've seen it.  If it were belongs_to :contact, would it be :contact_attributes?

Comment: I think it always has to be plural, so it has to be contacts_attributes. Did it work? Let me see your NEW and CREATE in your controller also.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues working with nested forms. As suggested by JustinRoR you need to define
attr_accessible: contacts_attributes.

You should be able to test the hash in the ruby console ( I am not sure if you have tried this). I suggest you to print the params[:message] and use this to create message from console like Message.new(params[:message]). (Note params[:message] is what you get by printing the params[:message]  hash).

Once it works in console it should work like charm

Comment: thanks...what should the hash contain?  Should it be message[contact][email]?

Comment: should look something like message =>{ account_name => "McKesson", topic => "testing a contact", body => "testing this", sender_id=> "", receiver_id => 23, "contacts_attributes"=>{ "0" => { email => 888@gmail.com, first_name => Ang, last_name => Name}}}. I am not sure how simple_forms deal with. Can you post logger.info(params[:message])'s output in your action and post it here so that we can inspect what simple form returns

Comment: I suggest you could try this f.simple_fields_for "message[contacts_attributes][]" do |fc|  to achieve the above hash

Comment: thanks, let me try and I will repost the hash....I did not have contacts_attributes, before, it was just contacts => {}